# Unable to select text in WPF TextBox inside a Popup

Tags: wpf, select, textbox, popup

I'm trying to host a multi-line TextBox in a status information Popup to show read-only, multi-line, scrollable information. The following XAML all works well, except that the text is *not selectable* (so the user can copy it).

```
<!-- Status info popup -->
<Popup AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Center" StaysOpen="False"
       PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type v:ModuleView}}}" 
       IsOpen="{Binding ShowingStatusInformation}">
    <Border CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Status Information"
                       Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />                        
            <Button Content="OK" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding ToggleStatusInfoCommand}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 5" Padding="20 3" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Button.CommandParameter><sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean></Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>

            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding StatusInformation}" 
                     Margin="6 6 6 3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                     MaxHeight="300" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

The corresponding properties on the view model:

```
    public string StatusInformation
    {
        get { return _statusInformation; }
        set
        {
            _statusInformation = value;
            _propertyChangedHelper.NotifyPropertyChanged(this, () => StatusInformation);
        }
    }

    public bool ShowingStatusInformation
    {
        get { return _showingStatusInformation; }
        set
        {
            _showingStatusInformation = value;
            _propertyChangedHelper.NotifyPropertyChanged(this, () => ShowingStatusInformation);
        }
    }
```

Does hosting the text box in a Popup somehow disable text selection, or is there a problem with my binding? I'm replacing a TextBox hosted in a modal window where the text is selectable.

**Update:** this is happening in a .NET 3.5 application with WPF hosted inside a Win Forms container.

Comment: I pasted this code in a project using WPF 4 and I can select the text in the TextBox.

Comment: This happens in a .NET 3.5 project with WPF hosted inside a Win Forms container.

Comment: @Zamboni: thanks for trying it in WPF 4. It narrows down the issue a bit.

Comment: Does it work in a standalone 3.5 WPF project? I wonder if it's related to the winforms container.

Comment: It works fine in a 3.5SP1 standalone project... @Tom, you might be on the right track.

Comment: @BruceBoughton: what happens if you try to click the button in your popup?  Does that work?  If that *does* work then I'd say it's nothing to do with WinForms hosting (because it's not breaking mouse input for the button)... but even a duff binding shouldn't stop the text selection from working.

Comment: @Dan Puzey: the button works.

Comment: It actually seems to be an issue on just my machine, works on a colleague's machine. Odd...

Answer (score 0):

At what point is your control instantiated - in the constructor of the winforms control or at a later time? Maybe you could try for Loaded or ControlCreated.

It sounds a bit like what is happening when ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop has not been called, but it is not callable with a popup.

A workaround could be adding a 'Copy' button...